# Oracle SQL - Display calendar seven days only (Dates)

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I print just 5 dates only based on this query below. It renders sometimes a full month or even 4 days when i try the following date ranges:

1. to_date('16032020','DDMMYYYY') - to_date('20032020','DDMMYYYY')
2. to_date('23032020','DDMMYYYY') - to_date('27032020','DDMMYYYY')
3. to_date('30032020','DDMMYYYY') - to_date('03042020','DDMMYYYY')
4. to_date('06042020','DDMMYYYY') - to_date('10042020','DDMMYYYY')

Query:

```
select e.employee_id,
       e.initials || ' ' || regexp_replace(e.surname, '\([^()]*\)', '') farm_manager,
       r.research_station_id,
       r.name,
       dr.attendance_date attendance_date
  from research_station r
  join employees e on (e.employee_id = r.farm_manager)
 cross join (select (to_date('16032020','DDMMYYYY') + rownum - 1) attendance_date from dual 
 connect by level <= to_date('20032020','DDMMYYYY') - sysdate + 1) dr
  join employee_jobs ej on (e.employee_id = ej.employee_id)
 where r.research_station_id = 2;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Digvijay S does not work out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for some sample data that demonstrates the problem **AND** the output you expect for your query. At the moment, "it goes haywire" does not give us any information (you may get an error, you may get an incorrect output but we don't know as "haywire" is not a well-defined term).

Comment: Please don't just edit out the confusing term and replace it with something only slightly less non-specific .... please [edit] in **ALL** the necessary information to replicate your issue (tables, data in those tables, expected output, errors you're getting, etc).